# Shared Preferences usage in flutter project

Tags: flutter, set, local-storage, sharedpreferences, loading

I am trying to use "shared Preferences in flutter project, but getting errors in implementation file called as "preferences_service.dart" in my project. Can you check where the errors are coming from or what are the mistakes I am doing in this file?

The first error I am getting in this file is in below (image-1):

[image: image-1]

Then, while returning "Settings()" in the below portion I am getting error in "username" (which can not be coded without the "toString()". Also,lines there containing "programmingLanguages" & "isEmployed" can not be entered without using the exclamation mark i.e. I have to tell flutter that these enums are non nullable types. this code block is in the below portion (image-2):

[image: image-2]

Above all when running this program it's saving data as we can see in the "Debug console" but when re-started this app is not loading the last saved data.

The complete "preferences_service.dart" file is shown here:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'models.dart';

class PreferencesService {
  //below code is for saving the data whenever we press the saved button
  Future saveSettings(Settings settings) async {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    await preferences.setString('username', settings.username);
    await preferences.setBool('isEmployed', settings.isEmployed);
    await preferences.setInt('gender', settings.gender.index);
    await preferences.setStringList(
        'programmingLanguage',
        settings.programmingLanguages
            .map(
              (lang) => lang.index.toString(),
            )
            .toList());
    print('Saved Settings');
  }

  Future<Settings> getSettings() async {
    final preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final username = preferences.getString('username');
    final isEmployed = preferences.getBool('isEmployed');
    final gender = Gender.values[preferences.getInt('gender') ?? 0];
    //final gender = preferences.getInt('gender');

    final programmingLanguagesIndices =
        preferences.getStringList('programmingLanguages');

    final programmingLanguages = programmingLanguagesIndices
        ?.map(
            (stringIndex) => ProgrammingLanguage.values[int.parse(stringIndex)])
        .toSet();

    return Settings(
      username: username.toString(),
      gender: gender,
      programmingLanguages: programmingLanguages!,
      isEmployed: isEmployed!,
    );
  }
}
```

The complete "main.dart" file is this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test_shared_preference_use/models.dart';
import 'package:test_shared_preference_use/preferences_service.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _preferencesService = PreferencesService();
  final _userNameController = TextEditingController();
  //INFORMATION
  //Defining default position of the RadioListTile button
  Gender? _selectedGender = Gender.female;
  //INFORMATION
  var _selectedLanguages = Set<ProgrammingLanguage>();
  var _isEmployed = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _populateFields();
  }

  void _populateFields() async {
    final settings = await _preferencesService.getSettings();
    setState(() {
      _userNameController.text = settings.username;
      _selectedGender = settings.gender;
      _selectedLanguages = settings.programmingLanguages;
      _isEmployed = settings.isEmployed;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(
            'User Settings',
          ), //Text
        ), //AppBar
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: TextField(
                controller: _userNameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Username:',
                ), //InputDecoration
              ), //TextField
            ), //ListTile
            //INFORMATION
            //How to write the radioListTile code with "enum" is defined below:
            RadioListTile<Gender>(
              title: const Text('Female'),
              value: Gender.female,
              groupValue: _selectedGender,
              onChanged: (Gender? newValue) => setState(() {
                _selectedGender = newValue;
              }),
            ), //RadioListTile
            //INFORMATION
            RadioListTile<Gender>(
              title: const Text('Male'),
              value: Gender.male,
              groupValue: _selectedGender,
              onChanged: (Gender? newValue) => setState(() {
                _selectedGender = newValue;
              }),
            ), //RadioListTile
            RadioListTile<Gender>(
              title: const Text('Other'),
              value: Gender.other,
              groupValue: _selectedGender,
              onChanged: (Gender? newValue) => setState(
                () {
                  _selectedGender = newValue;
                },
              ),
            ), //RadioListTile
            CheckboxListTile(
              title: const Text('Dart'),
              value: _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.dart),
              onChanged: (_) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.dart)
                        ? _selectedLanguages.remove(ProgrammingLanguage.dart)
                        : _selectedLanguages.add(ProgrammingLanguage.dart);
                  },
                );
              },
            ), //CheckboxListTile
            CheckboxListTile(
              title: const Text('Javascript'),
              value:
                  _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.javascript),
              onChanged: (_) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.javascript)
                        ? _selectedLanguages
                            .remove(ProgrammingLanguage.javascript)
                        : _selectedLanguages
                            .add(ProgrammingLanguage.javascript);
                  },
                );
              },
            ), //CheckboxListTile
            CheckboxListTile(
              title: const Text('Kotlin'),
              value: _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.kotlin),
              onChanged: (_) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.kotlin)
                        ? _selectedLanguages.remove(ProgrammingLanguage.kotlin)
                        : _selectedLanguages.add(ProgrammingLanguage.kotlin);
                  },
                );
              },
            ), //CheckboxListTile
            CheckboxListTile(
              title: const Text('Swift'),
              value: _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.swift),
              onChanged: (_) {
                setState(
                  () {
                    _selectedLanguages.contains(ProgrammingLanguage.swift)
                        ? _selectedLanguages.remove(ProgrammingLanguage.swift)
                        : _selectedLanguages.add(ProgrammingLanguage.swift);
                  },
                );
              },
            ), //CheckboxListTile
            SwitchListTile(
              title: const Text('Is Emoployed'),
              value: _isEmployed,
              onChanged: (newValue) => setState(
                () {
                  _isEmployed = newValue;
                },
              ),
            ), //SwitchListTile
            TextButton(
              onPressed: _saveSettings,
              child: const Text('SaveSettings'),
            ),
          ],
        ), //ListView
      ), //Scaffold
    ); //MaterialApp
  }

  void _saveSettings() {
    final newSettings = Settings(
        username: _userNameController.text,
        gender: _selectedGender!, //We are using exclamation mark to tell
        //flutter that this is ok.
        programmingLanguages: _selectedLanguages,
        isEmployed: _isEmployed);

    print(newSettings);
    _preferencesService.saveSettings(newSettings); //We call the
    //"PreferencesService" class to save the settings in the last screen.
  }
}
```

The complete `models.dart` is shown here:

```
enum Gender { female, male, other }

enum ProgrammingLanguage { dart, javascript, kotlin, swift }

class Settings {
  final String username;
  final Gender gender;
  final Set<ProgrammingLanguage> programmingLanguages;
  final bool isEmployed;

  Settings({
    required this.username,
    required this.gender,
    required this.programmingLanguages,
    required this.isEmployed,
  });
}
```

This is the `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
name: test_shared_preference_use
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0-63.1.beta <4.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  shared_preferences: ^2.2.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Thank you in advance.

Tried to modify my codes & correct them, but could not understand where I am making the mistake. I am expecting if you can correct code block/s & explain where I am making mistakes, so that I can successfully run this application - save & load data from local disk. This will help me a lot.